# How to test coercivity for implicit functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, limits, coercive

Let $F(y), F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which depends implicitly from the variable $y$.

My question is: it is possible to check the coercivity of $F(y)$? If yes, how?

Some examples or references are also very appreciated.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: This is a little vague. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no examples, I would like to understand what happens in general. Or better if a Theorem exists which can state coerciveness for implicit functions (under suitable assumptions).

Comment: What is coerciveness? How do you define it?

Comment: @WillM. I refer to this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercive_function